# Create type for dependent function parameters

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a function that takes two arguments. a string, which is the key to determine the second parameter type, which is an object. The correlation between the string and the object is typed in a separate type. I'd like to have full autocomplete and type safety when calling the function (I have achieved that) and in the function, by using if or switch statements! the type of the object should be derived by the string parameter.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
export type TLoginParameters = {
    username: string;
    otherrequiredparam: string;
    optionalparam: number;
}

export type TLogoutParameters = {
    detailsForLogginOut: string;
}



export type TStateMap = {
    login: TLoginParameters;
    logout: TLogoutParameters;
};


const edit = <K extends keyof TStateMap , T extends TStateMap[K]>(type: K, entry:T  ) => {

        switch(type) {

            case "login": {
                // i expected autocomplete for TLoginParameters- but it doesnt work :(

                const prop = entry.username;
                        
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }

// autocomplete works here

const result = edit("login", {username: "test123", otherrequiredparam: "test", optionalparam: 123 });
```

I tried a different type definition for the function

```js
 <O extends TConfigTypeMap, K extends keyof O, V extends O[K]>( type: K, entry:V   ) =>
```

but the result is the same.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i have added the missing type declarations TLoginParameters|TLogoutParameters

Comment: TS can't really do narrowing with generics, especially across variables (e.g., checking `type` doesn't affect `K` so it definitely can't effect `entry`).  You can use a destructured discriminated union as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOX8pN) instead. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining (or find a relevant dupe target).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: that certainly serves my needs :) thank you so much.

can you explain the (...args: EditParams) => void part? I think it is the only way to make it work right? for my understanding. do you see a way to type it without ...args

Comment: Why do you want to type it "without `...args`"?  Can you explain the use case so I can come up with alternatives?  You will need a rest parameter, so I'm not sure if it's the `...` or the `args` part you have a problem with.  If it's `args` you can use [destructured param names like this](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Pnw).  If it's `...` then that's the only type-safe way to do this that TS supports;.

Comment: I was just curious. i dont have a problem with it but i tried to make it typesafe without the restoperator and failed. now its much clearer for me :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is currently unable to use [control flow anlysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (the kind of narrowing you get when you check `type` in a `switch` statement) with [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Right now when you check `type`, the apparent type of `type` can be narrowed from `K` to something like `K & "login"`, but `K` itself stays unaffected. For all the compiler knows, `K` might be some wider type than `"login"`, like the full [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"login" | "logout"`.  Indeed it is possible for someone to call `edit()` with a first argument like `Math.random()<0.5 ? "login" : "logout"`, and then you couldn't assume that `type` being `"login"` implies that `entry` is `TLoginParameters`.

There are various open issues in GitHub asking for improvements to this situation, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to restrict calls so that `K` could not be a full union, but would be restricted to exactly one member of the union.  For now, though, it's not part of the language.  If you want to use generics, you can't easily use control flow analysis.  If you want to use control flow analysis, you can't easily use generics.

---

Your example doesn't actually show a need for generics, though.  Instead it looks like you want the `type` and `entry` parameters to be treated as [destructured members](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type.  Like, if it were a single variable `v` of type `{type: "login", entry: TLoginParameters} | {type: "logout", entry: TLogoutParameters}`, then you could check `v.type` and it would narrow `v.entry`.

Luckily you can get this effect by viewing `edit()`'s parameter *list* as a discriminated union of [tuple-typed rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).  Like this:

```
type EditParams =
  { [K in keyof TStateMap]: [type: K, entry: TStateMap[K]] }[keyof TStateMap]
/* type EditParams = 
     [type: "login", entry: TLoginParameters] | 
     [type: "logout", entry: TLogoutParameters] 
*/

const edit: (...[type, entry]: EditParams) => void = (type, entry) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "login": {
      const prop = entry.username;
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Here `EditParams` is a discriminated union of tuple types, and the input to `edit` is a rest parameter of type `EditParams`.  When you implement `edit`, the compiler treats `type` and `entry` as members of that union of tuple types, and when you check `type`, it automatically narrows `entry` appropriately.

This works exactly how you want, with the unfortunate downside that it's kind of ugly or at least confusing.  Still, this is the best we can do for now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBAVAMlA5gSwDsAFAQxlIFsQ4QYBnBAXgQG9gEEBXeuwqkAC4E9ODCK4A3BwRQ4ACzowQARy75lAEwjkqw0eMJSZUCHHxR+AGx0VKwwl0oAjOtIC+wUJFiIUaTBxcKC44MjsaOkYWdk5NGlJ8K3oAMVgggkIAeVD9MQkPLy9waHgkVHQMAGU4UloAWVIIZjYZKzwiYWwOkl1qWgZpTnbg3MC8ELC+yMHgd2kvf3QAUU18KbtomVYEAG0AaQQiBABrEGQoADNMGrqQRogAXWFdpeF9gBoEEEIxZC7bg0mgdHo8EO5dmcLtdqrUgU9gAB6ABU5QCq3W4So0QQMk4ezeCAARCMiESvj8-l0gkQsf0omCAD64-GcV4VYQkiahcnfX4wf7jUYbAQDehg4DIxFeADGllE3zWcGEAAoAHQa9loCn85DPBAYkWUegASmYAD4EAA3KD4TQtFVLHV-M1MS2xEQAd3WMvkCEdFTNHs4MtIvGJpMIROEwfxcsICogMFMLUpArVPD4AiGrIQzmUpBOOc4nhLXk8SMRCFIoSgcsoECskQQntgJ0YimUsvliGU9C4VkQLBASpVXMyvJ2mZg-GonNoogAjAAmADMvLkneUag0I9semJC7gG7MFms+-sCBXq-BJoWQA)

Comment: thank you so much jcalz. you pushed my understanding to the next level. ive added another repsonse to clearify the last uncertainties

Comment: If this answer helped you then I hope you'll consider accepting it and/or upvoting it.  If you have a followup question it should be posted as a new post, not appended as an answer to an existing question.  I can't commit to have the scope of a question expand in response to an answer, or else this becomes an extended one-on-one tech support session, which is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: accepted your answer :) thank you for taking your time and explaining in such detail. my reputation is too low at the moment. so i cant upvote. but i sure will in future when I have a higher reputation level