# Type for dependent function parameters (tuple type)

Tags: typescript

I have a followupquestion to [Create type for dependent function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647289/create-type-for-dependent-function-parameters/77652599#77652599)

The function should take up to 3 parameters which are typed in an object (see TMessageTypeMap of the example below)

I want both

- typesafety and autocomplete when calling the function (works with `IMessageFunction`)
- typesafety and autocomplete inside the function (works with (`(...args:TMessageTupleType) => void`)

I made two more comprehensive variations of the example in the question above. Do you see a way to combine the advantages of both approaches?

```js
export type TMessageTypeMap = {
    event: TEventTypeMap;
    config: TConfigTypeMap;
};

export type TConfigTypeMap = {
    login: {
        value1: string;
    };
    logout: {
        value2: number;
    };
};

export type TEventTypeMap = {
    eventNo1: {
        e1Param1: number;
        e1Param2: string;
    };
    eventNo2: {
        e2Param1: string;
        e1Param2: number;
    };

};


export interface IMessageFunction {
    <K extends keyof TMessageTypeMap, T extends keyof TMessageTypeMap[K]>(
        messageCategory: K,
        eventType: T,
        parameters: TMessageTypeMap[K][T],
        callback?: (evt?: any) => void
    ): void;
}

export type KeyKeyValue<O> = {
    [K in keyof O]: {
        [T in keyof O[K]]: [K, T, O[K][T], (evt?: any)=>void];
    }[keyof O[K]];
}[keyof O];

export type TMessageTupleType = KeyKeyValue<TMessageTypeMap>;

// Method 1: FunctionType Interface
// calling the function only showing possible combinations
// in the function types cant be derived correctly
const functionMessageFunction : IMessageFunction = (category, type, params, callback) => {
    if(category == "event") {

        // cannot inherit type
        if(type == "pi") {

        }
    }
}

// Method 2: Tuple Type
// strictly typed in the function but 
// calling it does not provide code completion
const functionMessageTupleType : (...args:TMessageTupleType) => void = (category, type, params, callback) => {
    if(category === "event") {
        if(type ==="eventNo1") {
            // works - type is derived correctly
            params.e1Param1;
        }
    }
}


// only correct parameters can be provided
const result = functionMessageFunction("event", "eventNo1" , {
    e1Param1: 1, e1Param2: "jkasdf"
})


// all "type"-combinations and params-combinations are suggested by typescript (eventNo1, eventNo2, login, logout)
const result2 = functionMessageTupleType('event', "login", {
    value2: 1
})
// even correct variations arent accepted by the compiler
const result2Variant = functionMessageTupleType('event', "eventNo1", {
    e1Param1: 123
})
```

Comment: Without better overload autocomplete support (see [ms/TS#26892](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26892)) then there is no way to do this while maintaining type safety completely; if you want this you will need to use a type assertion (or the like) to cross the divide between the generic call signature and the discriminated union implementation, possibly as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1L68W).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thanks that helped a lot. when you write up an answer ill accept it :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to satisfy both of those points simultaneously.  To get type safety inside the function implementation you will need to use arguments of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type.  But that makes your function look like multiple overloads, and autocomplete does not work well there, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#26892](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26892).  To get autocomplete you need the call signature to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), but generic function implementations cannot do the sort of discriminated union narrowing you are trying to achiever.

So you're stuck.  The closest you can get to having both is to use the type-safe implementation and then just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it behaves like the appropriate generic function.  Assertions are not safe, so you need to be careful that it is accurate.  Like this:

```
const functionMessage = ((...[category, type, params, callback]: TMessageTupleType) => {
    if(category === "event") {
        if(type ==="eventNo1") {
            params.e1Param1;
        }
    }
}) as IMessageFunction // <-- assert
```

The implementation of `functionMessage()` understands that `category` and `type` can be used to narrow `params`.  And callers only see relevant suggestions:

```
const result = functionMessage("event", "") 
//                                      ^
//                               eventNo1
//                               eventNo2
```

And yet you could completely lie to the compiler this way, say by implementing the function incorrectly:

```
type TWrongMessageTupleType =
    ["event", "eventNo2", { e1Param1: number; e1Param2: string; }] |
    ["event", "eventNo1", { e2Param1: string; e1Param2: number; }];

const whoops = ((...[category, type, params]: TWrongMessageTupleType) => {
    if (category === "event") {
        if (type === "eventNo1") {
            params.e2Param1;
        }
    }
}) as IMessageFunction // <-- still works
```

The assertion is accepted; the compiler has no idea whether or not `functionMessage`'s or `whoops`'s implementation is a correct `IMessageFunction`. It believes you when you say that it is.  So again, care is needed.  Because there's no way to get complete compiler-verified type safety here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-AvbjsBKGBQ3oM8LygHB-EceAaCvcFBLvPjuVwxpsPJEzOioszaOYk5eCCclbKWXhsOkzFuNRORsM4lSyLQAB1KBZAIe9iGg9dUCoOIWQsrhrNi7oICyazaEGY4JlyAp7jENLVWWM51hyvRyVbdsnRdODPUDXs4AAH2ihL4so3oUpYI5VVOcJzlyxZbiymY4GKlt7UdTtKp7VEZzU+AAHcAAsIAgMAMRoJ9X2fd8RTQr8f1IP8GPAwLgtCqDVwi8bEOQ1D0PIuBGsIoss2QsisIoxorIeujmH-cZGOydLWMevQOL0LieNC0F9NvOARLEySVkhEC4Bm6BMWweggA)